# Using Fullpagejs with react-router-dom

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom, fullpage.js

I am building a website using `Fullpage.js`, `React`, and `react-router-dom`. I create a `Link` in the second section in the `Fullpage` component, and I want this `Link` can take me to another `route` (`/anotherPage`):

```
// Fullpage.js
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

import { initFullpage } from "./initFullpage";

const Fullpage = () => {
  useEffect(() => {
    initFullpage();
  }, []);

  return (
    <div id="fullpage">
      <div class="section">Some section</div>
      <div class="section">
        <Link to="/anotherPage">
          Go to a special page.
        </Link>
      </div>
      <div class="section">Some section</div>
      <div class="section">Some section</div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Fullpage;
```

Additionally, I need another `Link` to go back from `/anotherPage` route back to the second section in the `Fullpage` component.

I made a [demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/ancient-cdn-1q557?file=/src/components/AnotherPage.js) here.

As you can try, if you click the link on the second section, `react` can route you to `AnotherPage`, but the `navigation` dots provide by `Fullpage` package is still there, and you can even scroll up and down, though this will cause errors. Also, if you click `Go back`, it will also break the App.

How to do it right? Thanks for your help!

Here is my `App.js`:

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import Fullpage from "./components/Fullpage";
import AnotherPage from "./components/AnotherPage";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/">
          <Fullpage />
        </Route>
        <Route exact path="/anotherPage">
          <AnotherPage />
        </Route>
      </Switch>
    </Router>
  );
}
```

Comment: Any reason why you are not using the [official fullPage.js wrapper for React?](https://alvarotrigo.com/react-fullpage/). Give it a try and see if it fixes the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found I don't need to use `Fullpage.js` to achieve the "scroll-full-page" effect. It's actually easy to achieve by CSS. Have a look at [`scroll-snap-type`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/scroll-snap-type).

```
// index.html
<div class="container">
  <section class="page">
    Page one
  </section>
  <section class="page">
    Page two
  </section>
</div>

// css
.container{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  scroll-snap-type: y mandatory;
  overflow: auto;
}

.page{
  scroll-snap-align: start;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

Then you can have `Fullpage.js` type scrolling effect. Then you can use `react-router-dom` without problem.